# Identify LEGO set which looks like helicopter

Tags: set-identification

Can you help me identify this LEGO set please?

[image]

Answer (score 18):

It looks like [31029](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=31029-1) Cargo Heli

I'm basing it on the Yellow Slope, Curved 2 x 1, and Dark Bluish Gray Slope, Curved 2 x 2 x 1 Double with 2 Studs

[image: 31029]

Comment: Great you save me !!

Comment: It looks like the OP has that set, but with a substitute opaque tail piece replacing the two translucent ones in the photo above.

Comment: Which pieces? According to BrickLink, the only non-opaque pieces are the tiny "cheese slopes" at the front.

Comment: I think @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket was referring to those red translucent looking windows on the side.  I think they're just decals maybe?

Comment: Hmm. I see them - I'm willing to believe the official photo was just under a lot more light, so you could see through them more easily. The ones in the poster's photo might just be reflecting the darker surroundings and thus look opaque. BrickLink says there aren't stickers supplied with this set.

Comment: I was referring to the vertical pieces on the tail on which the tail rotor is mounted.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket those look like compression artifacts to me, not real markings or translucency.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Yes, it's hard to tell exactly what we are looking at.

Comment: I have this set and can confirm that the 1x2 slopes on the tail are 100% opaque.